# Admob not showing in webview

Tags: android, layout, webview, admob

My ads are not showing, i'm trying to add them in my webview application. This is the main.xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

  <com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
                         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                         ads:adUnitId="a14f3ed10a5e4eb"
                         ads:adSize="BANNER"
                         ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR, TEST_DEVICE_ID"
                         ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"/>
<WebView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
     />

</LinearLayout>
```

Any suggestion??

Comment: The adMob is shown on the emulator, but not on my device. wtf?!?!

Comment: try to add some log files to the admob classes and see if you run into any issues in it.

Comment: What logcat output do you get when debugging on the device?  Perhaps there is a line in there saying "Ad Request successful, but no ad returned due to lack of inventory."  By saying `ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR, TEST_DEVICE_ID"`, that means the emulator is getting test ads.  You would have to replace TEST_DEVICE_ID with your actual test device ID to get test ads on your device.  This id can be found in the logcat output too when debugging on the device ("To get test ads on this device, add AdRequest.addTestDevice("your_device_id");").

Comment: eric you were right! now it's working fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to give the Specific ID to the addMob. Just see the Default Example on GoogleAddMob site and follow that.

Answer (score 0):

Use debug mode via Eclipse and launch and Sample Ad app from the developer.android.com. In LogCat search for "To get test" with Ctrl+F and you will see the id there.

Or check this link with detailed how to:
[Get ad id how to](http://webhole.net/2011/12/02/android-sdk-tutorial-get-admob-test-device-id/)